# self.after() function crashing TKinter program

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a program stop running for a certain amount of time to save CPU power. I have a self.after function that I want to run to make the program stop running for a set amount of time. However, it always crashes the program.

`self.after(int(self.timeSleep*1000),print("Sleeping."))`

The word `Sleeping.` is printed but the window crashes. I thought that `Sleeping.` should only be printed after the "sleep" was done. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I couldn't find another question like this. Forgive me if it's a stupid mistake as it's my first time using TKinter.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I am not getting any errors in my terminal. By crash I mean the window stops responding.

Comment: Are you sure the window crashes? Is it not just sleeping?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the same effect as below:

- execute `print("Sleeping.")`
- execute `self.after(int(self.timeSleep*1000), None)` which is the same as `time.sleep(int(self.timeSleep*1000))`.

You need to change it to use lambda:

```py
self.after(int(self.timeSleep*1000), lambda: print("Sleeping."))
```

Comment: This results in sleeping no longer being printed. However, the program still crashes every time it runs this code. If I let the window not respond for long enough, I get the error code `unable to alloc 236 bytes`. Not sure what's happening.

Comment: What is the type of `self.timeSleep` and its value?  If it is a *string of number* (like `'123'`), then `int(self.timeSleep)*1000` should be used instead of `int(self.timeSleep*1000)`.  The suggested change should not cause the crash.

Comment: It was an actual number not a string of numbers. I found that I have to thread that specific command in order for it to work alongside Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that doesn't require using `self.after`. Instead, you can use a thread to run this specific method, allowing you to use while loops and time.sleep without crashing the main GUI program.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think you can communicate between two threads and tkinter, which lead to your new Q. I suggest to use `after()` as per acw1668 says